# Adding Spring project and Angular 4 into one repository by one commit

Tags: java, git, angular, spring-boot, command-line-interface

I have created a Spring Boot app with Angular 4 project. The root looks like: (of course in `static` directory under the `resources` I have all `.js` files minified).
[image]

So now I have two `.gitignore` files - one for Java app and second one for Angular app. The question is how to push to one repository those two projects? It doesn't even detect changes which I made in files located under the `frontend` directory from Intellij. When I created a repo and tried to pushed the whole project, `git` doesn't see the frontend project. It sees only directory called `frontend` but nothing inside.

`.gitignore` from Java app:

```
target/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr

### NetBeans ###
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
.nb-gradle/
```

`.gitignore` from Angular app:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
/typings

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Answer (score 0):

What is an output for `git status` command? Did you add files under frontend to versioned files (`git add`)?

What's more, I would recommend to maintain only one .gitignore file. You should just merge them.